# Change JTextField Variable name with loop in Java

Tags: java

My JTextField Name is

> Query0, Query1, Query2, Query3, Query4

I am trying to change the name with the loop. Is it possible to do this in java

```
                String[] StoreValueFromTable = new String[5];
                String[] ColumName = new String[5];
                JTextField[] Query = new JTextField[5];
                for(int Count=0;Count<5;Count++){
                    StoreValueFromTable[Count] = "QueryTechnica"+Count;
                    ColumName[Count] = "QT"+(Count+1);
                    Query[Count] = new JTextField();
                    StoreValueFromTable[Count] = rs.getString(ColumName[Count]);
                    Query<Count>.setText(StoreValueFromTable[Count]);
                    Query<Count>.setEditable(false);
                    //Text Field Name is Query0, Query1, Query2, Query3, Query4
                }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Query0.setText(StoreValueFromTable[Count]); Query1.setText(StoreValueFromTable[Count]);
Query2.setText(StoreValueFromTable[Count]); Query3.setText(StoreValueFromTable[Count]);
Query4.setText(StoreValueFromTable[Count]);

Comment: changing the name? you can't change the name of a variable. you can create a second variable (with a different name) that points to the same object

Comment: @Stultuske Could you please give me an example??

Comment: What the `setText()` method does is that it updates the text value, that is, what is being shown, in the text box itself.

Comment: @rashedazad Person p = new Person(); Person p2 = p;

Comment: So what do you want to change? The content of the text box or the text box's variable name?

Comment: Text Box Variable name. @npinti

Comment: @rashedazad as stated earlier: you can't do that.

Comment: Ok let me see if I found one or not..  Thank you guys ..

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware that you can change the name of an actual variable, that being said, you could use a `Map<String, JTextField>` to accomplish your goal.

In this case, the key would be the name you want to assign to the JTextField. To rename, simply remove the old key and add the new one.